# Consuming purchase results in a null object reference

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

Billing flow launches successfully, and I receive the purchase receipt email. 
However the fatal error occurs when `client.consumeAsync(consumeParams,consumeResponseListener);` is called.

This is problematic because it means the purchase has not been consumed and can't be purchased again.

Button click:

```
public void onClick5Handler(View view) {
        billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, flowParams);
    }
```

setupBillingClient() is launched from onCreate() and results in a successful connection:

```
public void setupBillingClient() {
        billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(this).build();
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(CoinsActivity.this, "success" + billingResult.getResponseCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    queryProducts();

                } else
                    Toast.makeText(CoinsActivity.this, "failed" + billingResult.getResponseCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Toast.makeText(CoinsActivity.this, "you are disconnected from billing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            }
        });

    }
```

```
public void queryProducts() {
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add(COINS_5);
        skuList.add(COINS_15);
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);

        billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList != null) {
                            for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                                String sku = skuDetails.getSku();
                                String price = skuDetails.getPrice();

                                flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0)).build();


                                if ("coins_5".equals(sku)) {
                                    coins5Price = price;
                                } else if ("coins_15".equals(sku)) {
                                    coins15Price = price;
                                }
                            }


                        }
                    }

                });
    }
```

```
    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {

        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
            for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {          
                handlePurchase(purchase);
            }

        } 

        else if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {

        }

        else {   
             }
    }

    void handlePurchase(Purchase purchase) {

        if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            // Grant entitlement to the user.

                ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder()
                                .setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken())
                                .build();
                billingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, consumeResponseListener);

            }
        }
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClient.consumeAsync(com.android.billingclient.api.ConsumeParams, com.android.billingclient.api.ConsumeResponseListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.hundredriddles.CoinsActivity.handlePurchase(CoinsActivity.java:197)
        at com.example.hundredriddles.CoinsActivity.onPurchasesUpdated(CoinsActivity.java:168)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your client is not initialized or NULL. Check it properly or add the whole code to help you.

Comment: I've added the remaining code.

Comment: client should be replace with billingClient.

Comment: It references the same thing - BillingClient. The issue I've noticed is that the purchases list is null, but I still get the response code: 7 error, which doesn't make sense. Do I need to queryPurchases in some way before onPurchasesUpdated is run?